# Inf timestop glitch in roblox studio ( ServerScriptService.TheWorldServer.TS:35: attempt to index nil with 'Name')

Tags: lua, roblox

I keep getting this error The error is only for this code. It causes the timestop to be infinite Does anyone know how to fix it? The error is ServerScriptService.TheWorldServer.TS:35: attempt to index
nil with 'Name' Any help is very appreciated.

I have no idea how to fix this so I help is VERY helpful.

```
local music = game.Workspace.BackgroundMusic
local model = game.ReplicatedStorage.Stand
local InUse = game.ReplicatedStorage.InUse
local bacon = {}
local G = {}

model.BaconTimeStop.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    local find = workspace:GetDescendants()
    if InUse.Value == false then
        InUse.Value = true



        local Sound = script.TSSound:Clone()
        Sound.Parent = workspace
        Sound:Play()
        music:Pause()
        wait(1.8)

        local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

        local part = game.Lighting.ColorCorrection

        local goal = {}
        goal.Contrast = -2

        local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(0.2)

        local tween = TweenService:Create(part, tweenInfo, goal)

        tween:Play()
        for i=1, #find do
            local That = find[i]
            if That:IsA("Part") or That:IsA("MeshPart") then
                if That.Anchored == false and That.Parent.Name ~= player.Name and That.Parent.Parent.Name ~= player.Name and That.Name ~= "Baseplate" and not That.Parent:IsA("Accessory") then
                    That.Anchored = true
                    table.insert(bacon, That)
                end
            end
            if That:IsA("ParticleEmitter") then
                That.TimeScale = 0
                table.insert(G, That)
            end
        end
        wait(3)
        InUse.Value = false
        local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
        
        local part = game.Lighting.ColorCorrection

        local goal = {}
        goal.Contrast = 0

        local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(0.2)

        local tween = TweenService:Create(part, tweenInfo, goal)
        
        music:Resume()

        tween:Play()
        for i=1, #bacon do
            bacon[i].Anchored = false
        end
        table.clear(bacon)
        for i=1, #G do
            G[i].TimeScale = 1
        end
        table.clear(G)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you everything you need to know.

> ServerScriptService.TheWorldServer.TS:35: attempt to index nil with
> 'Name'

This is line 35:

```
if That.Anchored == false
   and That.Parent.Name ~= player.Name
   and That.Parent.Parent.Name ~= player.Name
   and That.Name ~= "Baseplate" 
   and not That.Parent:IsA("Accessory") then
```

You index multiple variables with `Name` as in `.Name` (indexing operator `.`).

One of these values is `nil`.

`That` cannot be `nil` as this would cause errors earlier.

print `player`, `That.Parent`, and `That.Parent.Parent` to find out which of them is nil. Then find out why and fix that. We cannot help you here. If it is a valid state simply avoid indexing or replace it by some default value.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for taking so long to respond but ive found the nil variable That.Parent.Name ~= player.Name do you have any idea how I can fix that